# I'm looking for a Delayed Countdown HTML code... Example:

Tags: html, timer

I want a number to display, and after so many seconds...
Lets say 15 sec, that number will countdown once....
then repeat again after so many more seconds.

For instance, I want it to appear that spots are being taken.

What do I need to add to it to get the affect that I am looking for?
Here is the code that I am using...

```
<center>
  <strong>
    <font face="Arial" size="6">
        <font color="#FFFF00">
            <script language="JavaScript" src="j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js">;</script>
            ONLY
            <font color="#FF0000">7
                <font color="#FFFF00">SPOTS AVAILABLE NEAR<font color="##FF0000">
                    <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>,
                    <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>.
                </font>
            </font>
        </font>
    </strong> 
</center>
```

Comment: Here is the code that I am using...

What do I need to add to it to get
the affect that I am looking for?


<center>
<strong>
<font face="Arial" size="6">
<font color="#FFFF00">
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js">
</script>ONLY  
<font color="#FF0000">7 
<font color="#FFFF00"> SPOTS  AVAILABLE  NEAR
<font color="##FF0000">
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>,
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>.</font>
</font>
</font>
</strong>
</center>

Comment: I've added your code into your question. As you can see you're missing a `</font>`. But actually no, that HTML is to throw away cause totally deprecated. `<font>` tag is deprecated, `<center>` tag is also deprecated, `<script>;</script>` the ˙;˙ is suspicious, `language="JavaScript"` is not needed.... Where did you get that code from?

Comment: Also `document.write` is considered a form of evil. You should really consider to rebuild everything from scratch.

Comment: also note that `//j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js` returns a 500 server error...

Comment: I found the codes from a Google search and pieced them together.
they work on my wix.com site, I just wanted to add another element to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var i = 7;

    function countdown() {
      if (i >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerText = i;
        i = i - 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
          countdown()
        }, 15000);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="countdown()">

  <center> <strong> <font face="Arial" size="6"> <font color="#FFFF00"> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js">; </script>ONLY <font color="#FF0000"><span id=counter>7</span> <font color="#FFFF00"> SPOTS AVAILABLE NEAR <font color="##FF0000"> <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>, <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>.</font> </font> </font> </strong> </center>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure how to do that... I've never used this program before.

Comment: Click the checkmark on left under the vote arrows.   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow